# React, SpringBoot and CSRF

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-security, axios, csrf

I am using Spring Boot Security:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I have disabled CSRF:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class AuthConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.csrf().disable();

    }
}
```

Using `npm start`, I run the following code in my React app:

```
         axios
            .post(this.state.targetUrl+'/mpbpm/triggerProcess', {
                headers: {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS'
                }
            })
```

The result is:

```
Failed to load http://localhost:8080/mpbpm/triggerProcess: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401.
```

Why has this failed? I am trying to learn React, I have dummy code trying to retrieve values from a server. What is the easiest way to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here:

```
         axios
            .post(this.state.targetUrl+'/mpbpm/triggerProcess', {
                headers: {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS'
                }
            })
```

you're adding custom headers and send cross-origin fetch which triggers preflight request. The server isn't prepared for this kind of traffic and everything results in an error. Remove those headers.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have changed it to:
`axios.post(this.state.targetUrl+'/mpbpm/triggerProcess')`

Now error is:
`Failed to load http://localhost:8080/mpbpm/triggerProcess: Redirect from 'http://localhost:8080/mpbpm/triggerProcess' to 'http://localhost:8080/login' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3002' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: So that is a CORS issue, which I resolved by adding  `@CrossOrigin`to my endpoint and removing the Spring Security dependency. Marking your answer as correct as it solved the initial issue. Thanks again